# Регулярное выражение для строки без пробелов и минимум с одной цифрой

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Надо написать регулярное выражение, удовлетворяющее условию:

1. В строке нет пробелов.
2. В строке есть минимум одна цифра.

Вот такой вариант

`^\S*[0-9]{1,}$`
в принципе работает, но не пропускает строки типа *123ABC*.
Прошу подсказки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сочетаем строку из не-пробелов `\S+` с позитивным просмотром вперед с цифрой `(?=.*\d)`

```
^(?=.*\d)\S+$
```

[Демо](https://regex101.com/r/Xso2fu/1)

Comment: Спасибо. Будем осваивать Просмотр вперёд и назад.

Answer (score 1):

`^\S*[0-9]{1,}$` находит строки, которые начинаются с ноля и более непробельных символов, за которыми есть 1 и более цифр, которыми строка и заканичивается (т.е. валидные строки выглядят как `DGE_ewq::323`, `111111`, а `123a` или `A12.` не проходят.)

Используйте

```
^[^\s\d]*\d\S*$
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/Wpbrdm/1) (69 шагов, [`^(?=.*\d)\S+$`](https://regex101.com/r/Wpbrdm/2) находит те же совпадения за 109 шагов из-за `.*\d`, если вы хотите использовать блок предварительного просмотра вперёд, используйте `^(?=\D*\d)\S+$`).

Подробности:

- `^` - начало строки
- `[^\s\d]*` - ноль и более символов, не являющихся пробельными символами и цифрами
- `\d` - цифра
- `\S*` - ноль и более непробельных символов
- `$` - конец строки.